# How can I show registration form inside modal?

Tags: plugins, php

I want to show registration form inside modal popup. Now I can use fancybox and show modal popup but how can I show registration form of wordpress inside that modal? Is there any plugin available for it or it we can do it in Wordpress itself?

Preferably, it would be great if even captcha is available in that plugin.

Comment: Jack, have you tried loading the register page as an iframe inside the model popup?

Comment: Just google how to write a custom WordPress login form, use that, and put it inside the fancybox div.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [form-lightbox plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/form-lightbox/) with Gravity Forms and Formidable.